# Results for $this->Post->find as array only in CakePHP

Tags: php, json, api, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

For my web service, I would like to have slightly cleaner output, following script in my controller:

```
$this->set('data', $this->Post->find('all'));
```

when run through json_encode looks like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1382822815,
    "data": [
        {
            "Post": {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "The title",
                "body": "This is the post body.",
                "created": "2013-10-26 15:19:31",
                "modified": null
            }
        },
        {
            "Post": {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "The title",
                "body": "This is the post body.",
                "created": "2013-10-26 15:19:31",
                "modified": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But the version I would like looks like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1382822815,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "The title",
            "body": "This is the post body.",
            "created": "2013-10-26 15:19:31",
            "modified": null
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "The title",
            "body": "This is the post body.",
            "created": "2013-10-26 15:19:31",
            "modified": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I know in my template I can go through the array recursively but I hoped there could be a more elegant solution for this.

Comment: What does your POST data actually look like (`print_r($_POST)`)?

Comment: I have just used Post model from the default blog example on CakePHP site, eventually this will be for another table I have in a MySQL database but I have used this as it is well known example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller:

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');
$data = array_map('reset', $posts);
$this->set(compact('data'));
```

Maybe this will be more elegant for you )